# Как вносить изменения с поддержкой старого кода?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, рефакторинг

Есть проект
В проекте есть заявки, у заявки есть время ее подачи. После подачи заявки идет долгая работа с клиентом.
Частенько приходят задачи такого типа:
Поменять что-то в коде для заявок, которые подаются с такого-то числа.
То-есть для старых заявок, должен работать старый код, для новых - новый.
Эти изменения разлетаются по всему огромному проекту как-то так:

```
if ($app->date > $dateOfChanges) {
  //делаем так
} elseif ($app->date > $dateOfNextChanges) {
  //делаем сяк
} else {
  //делаем по-старому
}
```

Поначалу это было нормально, но через время такое началось повсюду, начало бесить и требовать рефакторинга

Я решил попробовать сделать так:
Создаем класс MainTimeDependent, который пока не делает ничего, и при каждом добавлении подобных изменений создаем класс, например Changes, который наследуется от MainTimeDependent.
В этом классе мы описываем каждое новое поведение как отдельный метод, а в  классе MainTimeDependent в таком же методе описываем старое поведение.
Если появилось еще изменение NextChanges наследуем его от предыдушего Changes и тд.
В итоге клиентский код теперь выглядит так:

```
//внутри getChange мы смотрим по дате, и вызращаем объект класса MainTimeDependent, Changes или NextChanges
$changes = $app->getChanges();

//делаем так, сяк или по-старому, в зависимости от даты
$changes->doSomething();
```

На мой взгляд это решение попахивает костылями, т.к. уже полтора десятка наследований друг из друга, класс MainTimeDependent разросся через чур и тд.

Может быть кто-то решал уже похожие задачи и может подсказать лучшее решение?